# Application explorer shows "Default (cus) [CUS Model]"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

**Background:** I'm trying to edit an AX Report in Visual Studio. I have previously been able to create reports in VS and integrate them into AX. But I haven't used this in several weeks. Now, suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

**Symptoms:** When I open Visual Studio the Application Explorer does not show our actual AOS but instead says "Default (cus) [CUS Model]". ***update:*** As it turns out the Application Explorer does connect to the right AOS. It just displays this default name (and now since resetting VS user data is fixated on the USR-layer)

**Attempted solutions:**

- [Setting `/AxConfig` parameter in Visual Studio shortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889291.aspx). I have the *exact* same shortcut as my coworker who does not have this problem
- [Editing the Ax Config via `AxCliCfg.exe`](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/169502)
- [Importing, Applying, Refreshing and Re-Applying the .AXC file used to connect the AX client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991751/how-to-connect-visual-studio-to-a-specific-dynamics-ax-environment)
- Editing the registry keys for AxCliCfg both in LOCAL_MACHINE and CURRENT_USER
- A ton or restarting
- Checking permissions and roles in Ax, AOS Server, DB Server

I can't find anything else besides reinstalling everything. I've seen one reference to a KB2827469 that supposedly changes the way Visual Studio loads the AX configuration but can't find anything about that KB on microsoft's websites.

Comment: You can find [KB2827469](https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Resolved/1196432?kb=2827469) in the Lifecycle Services Issue Search, it's title is: "Visual Studio .NET launched from within AOT overlooks AxConfig parameter and any custom config profile."

Comment: Have you tried resetting your VS user data? `/ResetUserData` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @AlexKwitny The only thing this did was change the displayed AOS to "Default (*usr*) [*USR* Model]

Comment: @FH-Inway. Thank you very much for the link. But I can't access it. I don't have the necessary permissions...

Comment: To me this sounds like your very first link about setting the `/AxConfig` in the shortcut is not done correctly. Can you triple-check it?

Comment: I've realized that the Application Explorer actually connects to the right AOS but just displays the wrong name (and is now fixed on the USR layer). The bigger issue is that VS says that the reports in the project don't exist in the repository. I thought the issue described in this question was the cause for my bigger problem. **I'm unsure how to proceed:** should I update the question or start a new one?

Comment: Answer this question, then create a new question.